# How to rewrite WordPress uploads folder to another folder using htaccess

Tags: uploads, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I found that the following code online could be used to spoof the WordPress uploads folder, rewriting URLs to a different folder on the server:

```
# BEGIN Spoof wp-content/uploads directory
RedirectMatch 301 ^/uploads/(.*)$ https?://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/$1
# END Spoof wp-content/uploads directory
```

It is my understanding that under Media settings page the 'Full Path to files' needs to point to desired spoof folder.

I have tried using the above code but WordPress throws a error 404. My uploads are set to be organized by year and month. The file was that uploaded and tested indeed exists on the server.

Here is an example of the structure setup:

Real folder path -> http://yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/icon.jpg
Spoofed folder path -> http://yoursite.com/uploads/2011/09/icon.jpg

My question: Is there anything wrong with the rewrite code that could lead to the error 404 issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, this:

```
https?://yoursite.com
```

doesn't do anything you want, just make it `http://yoursite.com`. Next to that, make sure your server actually supports RedirectMatch.

Comment: Thanks, Joost! I am not even why I had that in there in the first place, but removing it was the solution.